# Rails 2.3.12: Routing 'GET /foo', 'PUT /foo', and '<any> /foo/bar' separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 2.3.12 app that is fronting for another application.  Call the other application `foo`; all URIs sent to my app will begin with `/foo`.  My Rails app needs to handle these cases:

1. `GET /foo` -- my app handles directly (returns a list of what's supported)
2. `<anything-else> /foo` -- returns a 401 (*i.e.*, `GET` is the only supported HTTP verb)
3. `<anything> /foo/<anything>` -- gets handled by my app to be passed to the `foo` app.

Unfortunately, all of my attempts so far have resulted in *everything* being fielded by either cases 1&2 or by case 3.  Here's what I have in my `routes.rb` at the moment:

```
     map.root(:controller       => 'application',
              :action           => 'render_401_unauthorised')
  map.connect('fooapp/*fooapp_ep_path',
              :controller       => 'foo',
              :action           => 'parsepath')
  map.connect('fooapp',
              :controller       => 'other_controller',
              :action           => 'index',
              :conditions       => { :method => :get })
  map.connect('fooapp',
              :controller       => 'application',
              :action           => 'render_401_unauthorised')
```

I think my problem would go away if I could ensure that the first `map.connect` would **only** match if `*fooap_ep_path` isn't empty -- *i.e.*, matches the regex `%r!/foo/.+!`

Can this be done?

Thanks!

**Updated** If there is any way to specify that a glob path **must** be [non]empty, that would probably provide the necessary glue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out using `#with_options` along the lines of

```
map.with_options({}) do |ap,*args|
  ap.name1('fooapp',
           :controller    => 'can_do',
           :action        => 'index',
           :conditions    => { :method => :get }
          )
  ap.name2('fooapp',
           :controller    => 'can_do',
           :action        => 'render_403_forbidden'
          )
  ap.name3('fooapp/*fooapp_path',
           :controller    => 'other',
           :action        => 'do_it'
          )
end
```